# Why isn't my managed object context being created?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data, uinavigationcontroller

Ok. I have a big problem. I recently downloaded [FRLayeredNavigationController](https://github.com/weissi/FRLayeredNavigationController) using Cocoapods. Before using it and simply using the `UINavigationController`, everything was working fine. Now its just a big mess. This is what I have after running the application: 
[image]

This is my code:
**AppDelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FRLayeredNavigationController/FRLayeredNavigation.h"
@interface TasksAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (void)saveContext;
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) FRLayeredNavigationController *layeredNavigationController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@end
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    ToDoTableViewController *tableViewController = [[ToDoTableViewController alloc]init];
    self.layeredNavigationController = [[FRLayeredNavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:tableViewController];
    tableViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    self.window.rootViewController = self.layeredNavigationController;
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

In my console I am getting the following:

```
DEBUG: self: 'ToDoTableViewController: 0x9537600', self.parentViewController: '(null)'
```

So basically what I can tell is that either for some reason `FRLayeredNavigationController` is not being created, or that the managed object context is not being created. I have no idea why. Literally if I change the `FRLayeredNavigationController` to `UINavigationController`, everything works fine >.>

If it makes any difference, `TableViewController` is not a `UITableViewController`, but rather a `UIViewController` with a tableView inside of it.

Comment: So which is it? Is the controller not being created, or the MOC? Or is the ToDoTableViewController's parent just not being set correctly? Should be easy to tell in the debugger.

Comment: I'm not sure. It could be both. Considering that the breakpoint is at NSEntityDescription it could be the MOC...but the console is saying that the FRLayerController is not getting sent into the view heirarchy t_T

Comment: @EvilAegis see my answer, it could help you...

Answer (score 0):

The `ToDoTableViewController` is not getting generated here. ManagedContext does not seem to be causing this. In your `ToDoTableViewController` do you have a property named 'parentViewController' which you are trying to access ?

Comment: no I don't :/ it must be part of the FRLayeredNavigationController I'm guessing

Answer (score 0):

Because of your breakpoint: Maybe check for random breakpoints in Xcode: Press <kbd>⌘+6</kbd> in Xcode to see all breakpoints. The log message however comes from a known limitation in [FRLayeredNavigationController](https://github.com/weissi/FRLayeredNavigationController): You cannot use `self.layeredNavigationItem` (or `someViewController.layeredNavigationItem`) until the view controller (`self` or `someViewController`) is actually pushed onto the screen.

FRLayeredNavigationController's [documentation on `layeredNavigationItem`](http://weissi.github.io/FRLayeredNavigationController/docs/html/Categories/UIViewController+FRLayeredNavigationController.html#//api/name/layeredNavigationItem) mentions that:

> Warning: This property is nil until the view controller is shown on the screen. To configure the FRLayeredNavigationItem before appearing on the screen use the following methods:
>
> [FRLayeredNavigationController initWithRootViewController:configuration:]
>   [FRLayeredNavigationController pushViewController:inFrontOf:maximumWidth:animated:configuration:]

The reason for that (I'm the developer of FRLayeredNavigationController) is that `layeredNavigationItem` is implemented by walking the view controller hierarchy and before the view controller is pushed, it's not in the hierarchy at all. Therefore, `parentViewController` is `nil`.